# Project is not support by this installation {BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3}

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-metro, windows

I get `Project is not support by this installation` error when opening a project in VS 2010 Pro

Looking at `<ProjectTypeGuids>` I see guid

```
{BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3}
```

Which indicates a `Windows Store Apps (Metro Apps)`

What should I install to run this project type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which indicates a Windows Store Apps (Metro Apps)

Correct.  Which requires at least VS2012, the first version that supports Store app development.  And you need at least Windows 8, required so you can debug your app.

Answer (score 5):

This type of project can be opened with Visual Studio versions from 2012 to 2015.
Starting with Visual Studio 2017, this type of project isn't supported any more.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs

Comment: That's helpful.