# Visual Studio 2012, monogame project, missing project subtype?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xna, monogame

The error is: Project subtype `BC8A1FFA-BEE3-8014-F334798102B3` is unsupported by this installation.  What does that mean?

[image: I'm not understand this bug]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project is not support by this installation {BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854448/project-is-not-support-by-this-installation-bc8a1ffa-bee3-4634-8014-f334798102b)

Answer (score 1):

This is the Guid for a Windows 8 store app. These type of projects can only be opened on a Visual Studio 2012 installation that is running on Windows 8 or 8.1.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19938817/736079